# Installed lamp on ubuntu server on an ec2 amazon instance, still can't access server through browser with apache running. Why?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, aws-security-group

I started an instance on amazon ec2, ami is ubuntu 14.04. I followed the steps on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html exactly up until "Transferring Files to Your Linux Instance Using the PuTTY Secure Copy Client" Since I don't need to put files on there just yet. Then I followed the following: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP.

"To install the default LAMP stack in Ubuntu 10.04 and above
First refresh your package index...

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

... and then install the LAMP stack:

```
$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Mind the caret (^) at the end. "

After that I tried

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

After which ubuntu said: `httpd (pid 5549) already running`

Yet when I try to browse with chrome to the public ip which shows in the amazon console I get

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

In my browser. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your security group settings. What are the inbound rules?
You need to add the IP(s) from where you are opening the web browser in the inbound rules. Also, check whether you are using private IP or public IP on the browser. You need to use public IP.

Comment: I used the public IP (the one that says public ip in the amazon aws console) in my browser, I think this is the right one. How do I check security group settings and inbound rules? I'm doing all of this through ssh with putty btw.

Comment: if you have not already installed awscli, install and configure it. You can google to find how to install it. Then, run: 'aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids yourInstanceId'. Get the Id of the security group (yourSgId) from the output you get. Then run: 'aws ec2 describe-security-groups --group-ids yoursgId'. Paste the output here in the comments. Basically you need to check the "IpPermissions" field in the output. All the above steps can be done from any linux based machine easily.

Comment: To know more details about security groups: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: Thank you. Marked as answer.