# httpd (pid 44) already running

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, geocoding, nominatim

I am trying to deploy an open source geocoding server onto the docker cloud linking to AWS EC2. The container works perfectly locally. But when I execute the start.sh command on the cloud. It always gives me error:

```
* Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
...done.
httpd (pid 44) already running
```

Then failed in starting up.
Any ideas how can I fix it or what goes wrong?

Comment: Is it related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34178687/6309?

Comment: @VonC Thank you! It answers my question.

Comment: Great! I suppose you could delete that question, then, since it is a duplicate of the other one.